# eliminar un elemento repetido de una lista por comprension en haskell

Tags: haskell

quisiera saber si es posible pasar esta funcion en una lista por comprensión, desde ya agradezco sus respuestas

```
deleteDuplicate :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate [] = []
deleteDuplicate (x:xs) = x : deleteDuplicate (filter (/= x) xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Una *comprensión de listas* no deja de ser *sintactic sugar* para hacer más manejables algunas sentencias. Pero no siempre es lo más simple, ni siquiera tiene porqué ser lo más eficiente. Supongo que quieres saber si existe esta alternativa por pura curiosidad.

El módulo `Data.List` tiene varias funciones interesantes, como la `filter` que usas en tu ejemplo (accesible porque la importas en el *Preludio* (*Prelude*)).

El módulo `Data.List` también tiene `nub`, que precisamente hace lo que pides:

```
import Data.List (nub)

deleteDuplicate :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate = nub
```

Creando una *perogrullada* se podría hacer la siguiente *compresión*:

```
import Data.List (nub)

deleteDuplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate xs = [x | x <- nub xs]
```

Sugpongo que no te vale esta solución y que buscas algo más elaborado y elegante.

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import Data.List (inits)

deleteDuplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate xs = [y | (y, ys) <- zip xs (inits xs)
                        , y `notElem` ys]
```

No es eficiente ya que está comprobando cada elemento de la lista con todos los anteriores para saber si está duplicado.

Las compresiones de listas no dan para mucho más. Si realmente buscas eficiencia --y evitar crear una función recursiva-- tendríamos que irnos a los *folds* de listas. Aquí sí que podemos hacerlo mucho mejor:

```
import Data.List (foldl)

deleteDuplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate = reverse . foldl f []
  where f ys y | y `elem` ys = ys
               | otherwise   = y:ys
```

También estamos comprobando un elemento con todos los anteriores para saber si está duplicado, además de tener que hacer al final un `reverse`, que también tiene su coste.

Pero se puede hacer una versión bastante más eficiente:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)

deleteDuplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicate = unfoldr f
  where f []     = Nothing
        f (x:xs) = Just(x, filter (/=x) xs)
```